# $.getJSON can't parse array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get data from json(array of objects) file using $.getJSON but i found this error: "success" function can't be executed. 
But it is executing if json contents object
What i'm doing wrong?

My code of JS and JSON below:
JS:

```
$.getJSON('test2.json', function(data){
      console.log('getJSON callback works');
      $.each(data, function(idx, obj){
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){
          console.log(key + ": " + value);
        });
      });
    });
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "user_name": "Name 1",
    "user_company": "Company 1",
    "message": "Message 2",
  },
  {
    "user_name": "Name 2",
    "user_company": "Company 2",
    "message": "Message 2",
  },
  {
    "user_name": "Name 3",
    "user_company": "Company 3",
    "message": "Message 3",
  }
]
```

Comment: your JSON file is not [valid](http://jsonlint.com/)  :)

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ is useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove "," at the last of each object

```
[
  {
    "user_name": "Name 1",
    "user_company": "Company 1",
    "message": "Message 2"
  },
  {
    "user_name": "Name 2",
    "user_company": "Company 2",
    "message": "Message 2"
  },
  {
    "user_name": "Name 3",
    "user_company": "Company 3",
    "message": "Message 3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try to catch error and success

```
$.getJSON( "test.js", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } )
  .done(function( json ) {
    console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.users[ 3 ].name );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
})
```